# Glmer with count data, repeat measurements and how to interpret output

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, count-data, ecology

I'm very new to mixed models (this is my first attempt) and have about 2 months experience in R so please forgive my ignorance. I am seeking guidance on my current project analysing the relationship between floral species richness and pollinator abundance using a Generalized Linear Mixed Model (GLMM).

**Summary of current model:**

**Response variable:** Pollinator_abundance.

**Fixed effects:** Floral_species_richness, Site.

**Random effects:** Transect, Count(1 or 2), n_orders(1-4).

I've chosen:

- Transect as a random effect due to non-independence in data collection along quadrats (5 per transect).
- Count as a random effect due to repeated surveys for each transect to avoid pseudoreplication.
- Unsure if treating the number of pollinator orders (0-4) as a random effect is appropriate.

Here's my current code:

`glmer(Pollinator_abundance ~ Floral_species_richness + Site + (1|Transect), family = "poisson", data = pollinators)`

I need guidance with the following:

**1. Validation of Fixed/Random Effects: Have I correctly identified these in the model? If not, how can I improve the model setup to better capture the data structure?**

**2. Interpreting the Output: How should I interpret the output, especially regarding the significance of fixed effects and the variance estimates for random effects?**

Any advice/guidance on how to refine the model and interpreting the results would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time and for your help,

Kindest regards,

Comment: To answer question #1, it will help to describe the data in more detail. It would be even better to share the data if that's possible. Question #2 is conditional on first making sure that the model is appropriate for the data.

Comment: I don't know what a pollinator order is (based on skimming one paper: fly, beetle, bee are pollinator orders?) so not sure it makes sense that it is a random effect. Treating a variable that takes two values (count: 1 or 2) as random effect is not recommended. Also, with the transects, are they labeled so that there are not transects with the same ID in different sites?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated post with a snippet of the raw data (unsure how to add all of it in as there are 240 observations). An order lies between larger groups like classes and smaller groups like species. For example, there are many species of flies which all belong to the order Diptera, bees (wasps, ants) to Hymenoptera, beetles to Coleoptera and butterflies and moths to Lepidoptera. Each transect has it's own site-specific code so no transects with the same ID across sites. Hope this helps. I will figure out how to add all the raw data if needed! Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Given the explanation, order might not be a good candidate for random effect. (Why? (a) there is a rule of thumb to have at least 5 levels for a factor to be random; this is due to practical difficulty estimating variances from few levels; (b) is it reasonable to treat the orders as exchangeable?) The easiest way to share data is with `dput()`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ah I see! So I will remove both n_orders and count as a random effect since both are < 5 levels. I have added in the full raw data, changed my code and output to reflect only using transect as a random effect. Does a GLMM suit this data or would another model be a better fit? Does the output suggest a 1 unit increase in floral species richness results in approx increase on 0.175 units in pollinator abundance. All sites show decreased pollinator abundance relative to intercept (Botanic Gardens) but the only site where this is significant is Victoria Park? Am I interpreting this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer. At the end I make a suggestion how to model the data but have low confidence in its usefulness. I have more confidence in the usefulness of the following two graphs.

First I plot the outcome, pollinator abundance, against number of pollinator orders. The points are jittered to reduce overplotting.

[image]

In a comment the OP explains:

> An order lies between larger groups like classes and smaller groups like species. For example, there are many species of flies which all belong to the order Diptera, bees (wasps, ants) to Hymenoptera, beetles to Coleoptera and butterflies and moths to Lepidoptera.

The clarification and the graph make it clear that n_orders is not exactly a predictor: If we know that pollinators from 4 different orders were observed, we know that the abundance is at least 4. (Abundance is number of pollinators.) So abundance and orders are two aspects of pollinator diversity and they are strongly correlated. So I'm not sure n_orders should be included as an explanatory variable. Aside: It would have been better to count the number of pollinators from each order. Then we could have fitted a multinomial logistic regression.

I also plot the outcome, pollinator abundance, against the predictor flower species richness, by site. Within each site, four transects are surveyed; these are indicated with a different shape. (There are 24 distinct transects; I use the same 4 shapes in each of 6 sites for readability.)

[image]

It's obvious from the graph that the relationship between flower richness and pollinator abundance varies a lot from site to site.

Therefore I suggest to add an interaction between flower richness and site. I also nest count (data collection survey) within transect, though it makes little difference as each transect was surveyed only twice.

```r
Pollinator_abundance ~ Floral_species_richness * Site + (1 | Transect / Count)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. It would be possible to run a multinominal logistic regression as I do have counts of the abundance of each order! The differences between sites is an interesting point in my discussion, considering differences in ecological and landscape features between sites. Thank you for this detailed answer and I will try to look into running a multinominal logistic regression!

Comment: Great. To be honest, I'm not 100% about the multinomial model -- that would be about modeling the distribution of the 4 different orders of pollinators. (See this [tutorial](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) about the multinomial model to learn more.) I mentioned it because I was thinking how there are (at least) two different aspects of "diversity", how many pollinators and which ones.

Comment: Still, a good place to start is one model that says something interesting about the scientific problem and fits the data reasonably well. So perhaps keep working on a model for the abundance first. You might look next at how to check the fit of a poisson regression.

Comment: If you think dipetkov's post answered your query, consider accepting it by clicking the tick symbol alongside the post.